# How to install Google test-analytics?

Tags: test-management, tools

I have read `How Google Tests Software` book and want to install `Google test-analytics`, but I can't because installation instructions are absent:

- https://code.google.com/p/test-analytics/issues/detail?id=5

I have cloned tool from https://code.google.com/p/test-analytics/source/checkout

Comment: Have you tried emailing the people on the wiki! The project seems somewhat dead with no updates for a couple of years

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try. And I know that project is dead but repository is still available. Okay, i will try to email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found fork on github with clear instructions: https://github.com/rodion-goritskov/test-analytics-ng

**How to build?**

1. You need Maven (http://maven.apache.org/) to build the
   test-analytics-ng project.
2. Clone this repo
3. If you have Maven version 3.0.X change the appengine-maven-plugin
   version in pom.xml to 1.8.3-maven3.0
4. Run

   mvn compile
5. Run

   mvn package

**How to run development server?**

You can take a brief tour through test-analytics-ng by making steps 1 and 2 of the previous section and then running:

```
mvn appengine:devserver
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't installed/deployed this, but if you are looking to just try it out, Google hosts an instance here: https://test-analytics.appspot.com/

Comment: I know it but I need to try this tool in production. So, I can not disclose details of the project(